# SQL Oracle: Find all the records available from same "ID", then select only the ones which have a specific activity state

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I can't find out how to write a query that:

Given this data with X (a lot) records:

| ID | Activity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | S | 2023/04/10 |
| 2222 | M | 2023/04/11 |
| 3333 | S | 2023/04/10 |
| 1111 | M | 2023/04/11 |
| 3333 | M | 2023/04/11 |
| 4444 | S | 2023/04/11 |
| 5555 | M | 2023/04/10 |
| 5555 | M | 2023/04/11 |

returns only the latest (by date) records with Activity state: "M" which don't have a previous record (in another date, from past or same day) with state "S".

As you can see, the IDs:

- 1111 --> Are X records, with S and M activities
- 2222 --> Is only one record, with M activity
- 3333 --> Are x records with S and M activities
- 4444 --> Is only one record, with S activity
- 5555 --> Are x records with only M activities

So I'm expecting to see as results:

- 2222 on 2023/04/11
- 5555 on 2023/04/11

In short words: I'm trying to find only the records with 'M' activities, and without 'S' activities, and pick the latest one using the date.

Thank you in advance,
Luca.

I've tried to think about a select distinct ID from table where Activity = 'M', but this won't guarantee me that for the same ID there aren't records with Activity = 'S' in the past days.

I've also tried to think about a group by ID, but same here, I'm not able to guarantee that the selected records don't have a previous record in another date, with activity 'S' in the past days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to find the latest row and check if there was an `S` activity earlier so that you only query the table once:

```sql
SELECT id, activity, dt
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn,
         FIRST_VALUE(CASE activity WHEN 'S' THEN 'S' END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
             PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC
             ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
           ) AS has_activity_s
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1
AND   has_activity_s IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, activity, dt) AS
  SELECT 1111, 'S', DATE '2023-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, 'M', DATE '2023-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, 'S', DATE '2023-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111, 'M', DATE '2023-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, 'M', DATE '2023-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444, 'S', DATE '2023-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5555, 'M', DATE '2023-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5555, 'M', DATE '2023-04-11' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | ACTIVITY | DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2222 | M | 2023-04-11 00:00:00 |
| 5555 | M | 2023-04-11 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xJtDETby)

Comment: Hello @MT0 thank you for helping me, I've accepted your answer since I think it's the most complete between the others. I've tried it and it works for what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

(Just setting date format, to know what is what; it isn't clear from data you posted as e.g. 2023/04/10 can be 10th of April as well as 4th of October).

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, activity, datum) as
  2    (select 1111, 'S', date '2023-04-10' from dual union all
  3     select 2222, 'M', date '2023-04-11' from dual union all
  4     select 3333, 'S', date '2023-04-10' from dual union all
  5     select 1111, 'M', date '2023-04-11' from dual union all
  6     select 3333, 'M', date '2023-04-11' from dual union all
  7     select 4444, 'S', date '2023-04-11' from dual union all
  8     select 5555, 'M', date '2023-04-10' from dual union all
  9     select 5555, 'M', date '2023-04-11' from dual
 10    )
```

Query begins here; `temp` CTE sorts all rows (for `ID`s that don't have activity `S`) per every `ID` by `datum` in descending order):

```
 11  temp as
 12    (select a.id, a.activity, a.datum,
 13       row_number() over (partition by a.id order by a.datum desc) rn
 14     from test a
 15     where not exists (select null
 16                       from test b
 17                       where b.id = a.id
 18                         and b.activity = 'S'
 19                      )
 20    )
```

Finally, return row(s) that ranked as the highest:

```
 21  select id, datum
 22  from temp
 23  where rn = 1
 24  order by id;

        ID DATUM
---------- ----------
      2222 2023/04/11
      5555 2023/04/11

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello Littlefoot, I've tried your answer and everything works fine, thank you for your help! I've accepted @MT0 answer since I found it more complete and it was easier for me to understand it, but thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Provided  'M' < 'S'

```
with mx as(
  SELECT tbl.*, MAX(Activity) over (partition by ID) ma, max(Dt) over (partition by ID) mdt
  FROM tbl
) 
select ID, Activity, Dt
from mx
where ma ='M' and dt = mdt
```

Comment: Hello @Serg, I've found your answer a little bit more complex than the previous from the other guys, also I didn't find a way to make it work for me, I mean it gives me different results from the other two answers, anyway I've found a solution so thank you for trying to help me

Comment: @VolturnoLuca,  It returns the same two rows for me  https://dbfiddle.uk/fu9Nc5AM

Comment: It's weird when I've added more filters it didn't show the same results as the other two answers, dunno what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one:

```
select * from data d1
where d1.Activity = 'M' and not exists(
    select 1 from data d2
    where (d1.id = d2.id) and (
        (d2.dat <= d1.dat and d2.Activity = 'S')
        or (d2.dat > d1.dat and d2.Activity = 'M')
    )
)
```